# In Map if we do modification with existing keys we are not getting ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have below codes  and i would expect from case 2 scenario to throw `ConcurrentModificationException` ,but it runs successfully. As I know If i do the same thing with single key in map it does not throw exception because [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556487/it-does-not-throw-exception-concurrentmodificationexception)
but again when I am reproducing this scenario having multiple keys with two cases -

1. modification by new key.
2. modification by  existing key.

Case 1:

```
    Map<String,String> mp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mp.put("1", "10");
    mp.put("2", "11");
    mp.put("3", "12");
    mp.put("4", "13");

    for (String key :mp.keySet()) {
        mp.put("5", "14");
    }
```

This will work as expected , throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Case 2:

```
    Map<String,String> mp = new HashMap<String,String>();
    mp.put("1", "10");
    mp.put("2", "11");
    mp.put("3", "12");
    mp.put("4", "13");

    for (String key :mp.keySet()) {
        mp.put(key, "14");
    }
```

It will not throws `ConcurrentModificationException`. Why ??

Answer (score 4):

In first case you are *modifying the structure of the map* so you get CME (adding a new key / value pair). In the second case you are not modifying the structure (overwriting values for *existing* keys). so you won't get CME

Answer (score 1):

ConcurrentModificationException is thrown when its structure gets changed while iterating over it but in second case there is no change in structure . It means there is just update for existing key in map (neither addition or deletion in second case which would have caused change in structure)

See http://javahungry.blogspot.com/2014/04/fail-fast-iterator-vs-fail-safe-iterator-difference-with-example-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

You can refer [to the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> The iterators [...] are fail-fast: if the map is ***structurally modified*** at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

And the definition of structural modification can be found there too:

> A structural modification is any operation that adds or deletes one or more mappings; ***merely changing the value associated with a key that an instance already contains is not a structural modification***

Finally, it is worth also reading the last paragraph:

> Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` ***on a best-effort basis***. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.